# Converting WebService from vs2008 to vs2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

So I converted a webservice from VS2008 to VS2010.

when I run it in the debugger, instead of opening the page where I can choose a web method, like in 2008, the browser asks me if I want to open the aspx file in visual studio

I'm sure this must have been encountered by somone before in the past. But my googling skills failed me...

Anyone know how to fix this so it behaves as I expect from working in vs2008?

Thanks,

Cal-

Comment: Why the down vote? I googled well before asking... If the question is so trivial it deserves a downvote, then why didn't the downvoter answer it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured it out.

I created a new webservice in the project by following the steps here:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1597083.aspx/1

It ran as expected.

So I changed the old web service from 4.0 back to 3.5, then changed it back again to 4.0.

Ran the project and everything worked.

For what its' worth, when I upgraded the project, I let VS2010 change it ot 4.0 automatically, perhaps this was the mistake. If I do it agian soon, I'll leave it 3.5 then manually change it to 4.0 that's worked for other webapps (though not tested on a service)

Thanks,

Cal-